# Why did my question get downvoted without any comment or reason given?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

[My question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416843/how-to-write-a-pointer-chasing-benchmark-using-64-bit-pointers-in-cuda) got downvoted but no comment was given, and no edits suggested. I have added edits, but these should have been suggested rather than downvoting without explanation.

I fail to see how I can fix it. It's an important question for me and because of the downvote, I might not get views, let alone answers. Why does this unexplained downvoting happen and how should users like me tackle it? Is there something wrong with my question?

I fear my question will not be seen at all. Should I repost the question (I don't think that's recommended, but I don't know what to do)?

Also, I have seen many other questions on Meta asking similar things, but I would like a specific answer for my question if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Funny, I had an upvote, and then a downvote on this question too. Please, tell me what's wrong, or I will never know.

Comment: A downvote implies something: "This question does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful"

Comment: In this case, that is because an answer to that would require full-on tutoring and an exhaustive explaination of multiple base concepts of the language, making this question in its current scope far too broad for the site.

Comment: *"I urgently require an answer"* - SO [isn't a helpdesk](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/248731), if that's the case you'd be better off looking elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase that. By 'urgent' I didn't mean I need a quick answer. It only meant it was quite important and I really don't want my question unnoticed because of unnecessary downvotes. I'll change that.

Comment: *"an anonymous downvote"* There is no other kind, all voting is anonymous.

Comment: We don't have, (in general), the same hardware or software environment.  We can't build it, test it or debug it.  What do you thnk that we can do that you cannot do much more easlily and safer?

Comment: I need an idea how to do it. My question is quite specific and anyone GPU expert working on CUDA will be able to help. I hardly think it requires anyone to build it themselves.

Comment: Did you delete the question?  All your questions have >= 0 upvotes.  Don't stress over a single downvote.

Comment: @Will, no I haven't deleted it. I have linked to it in the beginning of this question. It was not just one - it had got upto 6 downvotes actually, but after editing it, it's back to a non-negative number.

Comment: Missed that.  You did a great job fixing your question.

Comment: Thank you. It's still attracting more downvotes than upvotes though, but at least it's not closed as too broad anymore.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Each time I post a question here, there is someone that is downvoting without reason. So how can I contact with the administrator of stackoverflow in order to know which person is and block it? thx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question basically asks for someone to go ahead and explain you the entirety of the innerworkings of the benchmark tool you are discussing, and then suggest how to modify it. That would be a completely exhaustive answer and would need to explain multiple core concepts of [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and C in general.

Such a question is *too broad* for this Q&A format, and reflecting that, the question has garnered some close votes and downvotes.

For future reference, downvotes do imply a reason, if you hover over the downvote button you will see:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful.

Comment: Like I said in another comment, I am not referring to their entire benchmark file. It's just one line of code that will require change.

Comment: @kv.333 We both know that just changing a line of code without knowing exactly what the implications are in a complex program will have almost always only undesireable effects.

Comment: @kv.333 maybe you are also just not explaining very well what you want, because currently, it sounds like you want to customize a benchmark tool of which you have currently no exact idea how it works entirely.

Comment: Yes, which is why I don't want to risk changing the code myself. But I am sure the rest of the code will remain the same, because it is part of a small microbenchmark. I have added an edit, do you think it sounds better explained and more specific now?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I believe my question is clearer now. But I do feel like people upvote/downvote without reading properly. It makes it a little hard for less experienced users like me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: 'Yes, which is why I don't want to risk changing the code myself.' - when you have all the docs, code compiler, linker, environment, debugger, logger etc. and we have.. a blog post?  Do you see the inherent illogic there?

Comment: @Martin, actually no, I can't run the code I posted. I don't have the appropriate environment. That code works on a different GPU with 32-bit pointers. That's why I asked the question, and I have explained it in the description.

Answer (score 8):

I withhold my opinion on the question altogether, but this caught my eye:

> How do I modify the benchmark which originally deals with 32-bit pointers, in order to measure global memory latency using 64-bit pointers?

That *sounds* incredibly broad.  Since I know little about CUDA I can't really tell you, but the visceral reaction would be the downvote and close.

Comment: Actually, it's just one line of code that will require change. I am sure someone who understands GPU architecture and pointers better than me will be able to answer it.

Comment: If you believe that you can reword it so it legitimately doesn't sound like you're trying to take on an *entire* benchmark (which conceptually sounds huge), but only this tiny sliver, then I encourage you to do so.  The way it's phrased leads the less indoctrinated with CUDA to think you're asking for something massive.

Comment: Thank you, I have added an edit. Do you think it sounds more specific now?

Comment: @kv.333:  Not really, no.  I did literally mean a rewording of your post so that it seemed to read less like you're taking on the entire benchmark and more like you're trying to solve a specific problem via utilizing this benchmark.

Comment: Okay. I have reworded it as much as I can. It sounds specific to me. And I have refrained from using the word 'benchmark' and have used 'one of the microbenchmarks' instead. Does this sound better?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I believe my question is a lot clearer now, even to me.